# solving the recurrence T(floor[n/2]) + T(ceil[n/2]) + n - 1

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I have the following recurrence:

```
T(n) = c for n = 1.
T(n) = T(floor[n/2]) + T(ceil[n/2]) + n - 1 for n > 1.
```

It looks like merge sort to me so i guess that the solution to the recurrence is Θ(nlogn). According to the master method i have:

```
a) Θ(1) for n = 1 (constant time).
b) If we drop the floor and ceil we have: (step1)
   T(N) = 2T(N/2) + n - 1 => a = 2, b = 2.
   logb(a) (base b) = lg(2) = 1 so n^lg(2) = n^1 = n
```

Having a closer look we know that we have case 2 of master method:

```
 if f(n) = Θ(log(b)a) our solution to the recurrence is T(n) = Θ(log(b)a log(2)n)
```

The solution is indeed T(n) = Θ(nlogn) but we are off my a constant factor 1.
My first question is:
at step 1 we dropped of ceil and floor. Is this correct ? The second question is how do i get rid of the constant factor 1 ? do i drop it ? or should i name it d and prove that n - 1 is indeed n (if so how do i prove it ?). Lastly is it better to prove it with the substitution method ?

Edit: if we use the substitution method we get:

```
  We guess that the solution is O(n). We need to show that T(n) <= cn.
  Substitutting in the recurrence we obtein 
  T(n) <= c(floor[n/2]) + c(ceil[n/2]) + n/2 - 1 = cn + n/2 - 1
```

So it is not merge sort ? What do i miss?

Comment: What you missed is that cn + n/2 - 1 = (c+1/2)n - 1 is not less than cn for n large.

Comment: thanks man. so it is indeed nlogn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was long time ago, but here goes

### Step 1 we dropped of ceil and floor. Is this correct ?

I would rather say

```
T(floor(n/2)) + T(floor[n/2)) <= T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil[n/2)) 
T(floor(n/2)) + T(ceil[n/2)) <= T(ceil(n/2)) + T(ceil[n/2))
```

in case they are not equal they differ by 1 (and you can ignore any constant)

### The second question is how do i get rid of the constant factor 1 ?

You ignore it. Reasoning behind it is : even if constant is huge 10^100 it will be small compared to the size when n grows larger. In real life you can't really ignore really big constants, but that is how real life and theory differs. In any case 1 makes smallest amount of difference.

### Lastly is it better to prove it with the substitution method

You can prove how you like, some are just simpler. Simpler are usually better, but other then that 'better' has no meaning. So my answer is no.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer, i did use substutution method to check if i am correct and it seems i am not. I editted my pos t can you please take a look ?Wait a sec i edit it again one minute.